# No new races appearing in Need For Speed: Underground 2

Tags: need-for-speed-underground-2

I'm playing NFS: U2 in story mode, and I finished all the races provided by the game, but no new ones are appearing!

What can I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, a certain star rating with your car is necessary for progress. Visit a Body Shop, a Car Specialities Shop, a Graphics Shop or any other garage where you can increase your star rating.

If you do so, and reach a certain rating, magazine cover missions are going to appear immediately when you leave the garage.

Comment: That's not how you use this site, you basically answered your own question, defeating the purpose of "QnA" because you already know the answer!

Comment: @Mano Have a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking Answering your own questions is allowed and encouraged. There is also a checkbox explicitly for this when you ask a question to answer it right away.

Comment: @Mano are you aware that the possibility is provided [by the very site itself?](http://i.imgur.com/N5PD428.png?1) It also doesn't means *others* are not allowed to answer, so everything's fine.

Comment: I don't read everything on meta, and I have never asked a question within these sites. It just looked strange for a moment, I apologise.